# Athena Presto list empty tables

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I would like to list all empty tables in my database Athena.

I tried :

```
select table_schema, table_name from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'database'
```

But like this I list only table name with database name.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think it is possible within a single query. Your query gives you a list of tables. Having that I think you could now iterate over that from the external tool.